# MEAN npm install

Tags: node.js, mean, npm-install

I followed the [MEAN Official Documentation](http://learn.mean.io/) to install MEAN on my Ubuntu 14.04 x64-bit machine.
Everything went well as described on the documentation until I reached the `npm install` section. When I run the command I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/hooker/-/hooker-0.2.3.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/hooker/-/hooker-0.2.3.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/jshint/-/jshint-2.8.0.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/mongoose/-/mongoose-4.3.3.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.4.11.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/swig/-/swig-1.4.2.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.2.11.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.2.11.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.4.2.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-1.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-1.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/bluebird/-/bluebird-2.9.34.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.3.3.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie/-/tough-cookie-2.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie/-/tough-cookie-2.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-2.4.24.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-2.4.24.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.13.5.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.13.5.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-3.1.0.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /tmp/npm-7892-4a9f0047/registry.npmjs.org/hawk/-/hawk-3.1.0.tgz
```

And the process doesn't stop. No error logs nothing.

`node -v` returns `v4.4.2`
`mean -v` returns `0.11.1`
I have already tried `npm cache clean` as well as tried to install node from scratch but no luck.

Comment: do you have enought space on `/tmp` ?

Comment: out of 19.4GB on my `/` , `/tmp` has used just 23.9MB . I guess that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: there is an issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5133. try to use `npm cache clean` + `npm update` + `npm install`

Comment: `sudo npm update` or `npm update` gives following error too:
`npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-69-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "update"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6

npm ERR! shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-9753-bdea406f/registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-2.0.0-rc.3.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 1fae1160594dd47dbe5431d4726d66b10f374d89
npm ERR! Actual:   4c0b1eb3eff2dcdbbc81458913659633b97e7154
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-2.0.0-rc.3.tgz
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>`

Comment: try `npm install --no-bin-links`

Comment: I'm on it. Will post the progress soon...

Comment: The error I get is similar as above.... is it really this painstaking to configure MEAN stack?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using  `sudo`

Comment: check the permissions you have in that folder, but that should work with sudo... you can try anyway

Comment: No issues of permissions. I don't think that is the issue here.

Comment: it is possible for you to install another module?  try to install another module  Im checking the documentation.